# jQuery create element with attribute differences

Tags: jquery

Discovered something and am looking into a bit of incite as to why one way works and the other doesn't.  Looks to be only an IE7 thing but as IE7, sigh, still needs some support in the apps I work in.

Way that works in IE7

```
var month = jQuery('<input/>');
month.attr('id', 'DOBmonth');
month.attr('title', 'Enter month');
month.attr('type', 'text');
month.attr('size', '1');
month.attr('maxlength', '2');
month.attr('class', 'numbersOnly');
month.attr('value', mm);
```

This way doesn't work

```
var month = jQuery('<input/>', {
        id: 'DOBmonth',
        title: 'Enter month',
        type: 'text',
        size: 1,
        maxlength: 2,
        class: 'numbersOnly',
        value: mm
        });
```

Anyone have an idea why only one way works in IE7 but either is fine in IE8+, FF, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Do you get Javascript errors using the second way in IE7?

Comment: IE7 and earlier have a write-once policy vis-a-vis `type` on `input` elements (once you set it, you can't change it). Guessing (hence not posting an answer), that for whatever reason, the first example is falling afoul that policy and the second isn't. Again, not an *answer*, but perhaps some insight.

Comment: also class should be in quotes for IE

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer can be found in the API for the [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) function itself.

> Note: Internet Explorer will not allow you to create an input or
>   button element and change its type; you must specify the type using
>   `<input type="checkbox" />` for example. A demonstration of this can
>   be seen below:
>
> Unsupported in IE:
>
> ```
> $('<input />', {
>     type: 'text',
>     name: 'test'
> }).appendTo("body");
> ```
>
> Supported workaround:
>
> ```
> $('<input type="text" />').attr({
>     name: 'test'
> }).appendTo("body");
> ```

Answer (score 5):

[according to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> Note: Internet Explorer will not allow you to create an input or button element and change its type; you must specify the type

this doesn't work:

```
$('<input />', {
    type: 'text',
    name: 'test'
}).appendTo("body");
```

but this does:

```
$('<input type="text" />').attr({
    name: 'test'
}).appendTo("body");
```