# jQuery - how to set title attribute in a particular format

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have this jQuery code as part of a loop to generate divs  and set properties for each div.

```
var names = $('<div/>', {
         id: load1array[j],
    'class': 'bold',
     html: load1array[j]
        });
```

I want to add a title attribute for each div, but I forgot the syntax.  I have tried the codes below but they don't appear to be the right syntax.

```
var names = $('<div/>', {
         id: load1array[j],
    'class': 'bold',

//attr:('title','text here'),        
//title:'text here' ,    
//'title':'text here' ,  

        html: load1array[j]
        })//.attr( "title", "text here" );
```

TIA

Edit:

I also saw the answer here [Creating a div element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery), which shows that the code that includes the title attribute

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    href: 'http://google.com',
    title: 'Become a Googler',
    rel: 'external',
    text: 'Go to Google!'
}).appendTo('#mySelector');
```

But it did not work as I have tried, following the answer's included links, perhaps the title attribute does not work with `<div>` tags, but rather `<a>` tags.

Comment: Are you sure         'title':'text here' ,       didn't work? I'm 99% sure that's correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery create element with attribute differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898442/jquery-create-element-with-attribute-differences)

Comment: It works fine: http://codepen.io/Fresheyeball/pen/Foayb Your problem is not this syntax. Its something else.

Comment: seems to ne fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/brFyZ/1/

Comment: Thanks, the code apparently works with your link for all 3 variations: title:'text here',  'title':'text here', and append at the end .attr( "title", "text here" ).  Maybe the problem is with assigning the code to a variable.  The easy solution is suggested by ivowiblo, but it is still perplexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var names = $('<div/>', {
     id: load1array[j],
'class': 'bold',
 html: load1array[j]
    });

names.attr("title", "text here");
```

Comment: Thanks ivowiblo, this code works as expected. But I don't get why it does not work when I chained it to the end of the statement.